# Storing HTML file rendered by JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I need to create a report using Servlet and jsp. My problem is this, there is a page which list the previously generated report. One can click on any of this report from list and view that report again. For this I have to keep the static html file Rendered by the jsp on the server. 
How can i obtain this. I don't want to render the jsp file twice as this is time consuming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should write the body of your HTTP response object to a file on your webserver and write some kind of service/servlet to retrieve these files.
I guess the easiest way to do this, is by writing a ServletFilter that intercepts the responses of your JSPs.

The current Oracle Java EE 6 tutorial is rather brief about Filters, but you can read all about them in the previous version : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the reports by adding a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). The filter can check if an already rendered version is available and return the contents of that file. If no file is present it can write the resulting response to the cache.